# MATLAB "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Tags: matlab

In the MATLAB examples page for Computer Vision System Toolbox, there is a code for Object Detection in a Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching. I am running the same code on my system, however it is giving the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" where the code tries to match the similarity between the two images.

```
I1 = rgb2gray(imread('kitchen.jpg'));
I2 = rgb2gray(imread('loops.jpg'));
points1 = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
[features1, valid_points1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);
[features2, valid_points2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1, features2);
matchedPoints1 = valid_points1(indexPairs(:, 1), :);    //ERROR
matchedPoints2 = valid_points2(indexPairs(:, 2), :);
figure; showMatchedFeatures(I1, I2, matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2);
```

I am new to MATLAB and just trying to understand the concepts however I got stuck in this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think it means the subscript indices are not positive integers or logicals. So I'd check to see if `indexPairs(:,1)` is an array of positive integers or logicals or something else.

Comment: The `indexPairs` is an array of 0's and positive numbers wherever it manages to find a match between the two images.

Comment: So is it an array of logicals (1's and 0's only) or numbers (all integers between 1 and the maximum size of the array you are indexing in to)?

Comment: It is an array of 0's and numbers pertaining to the indices location, so positive integers.

Comment: Well that's why you are getting an error. The indexes can be logicals **OR** integers, not both.

Comment: I changed the value to 1. So now it prints either 1 or a matching indices location. However the output changes to give only one probable match between the two images, in contrary to all the possible matches between them. This is the link to the code from the mathwork website:http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html

Comment: You can't mix logical and integer indexing. The 1's will index the first element of the array, and the other integers will index other elements. Read [this article](http://au.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and try some examples for yourself so you understand how Matlab matrix indexing works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (with some slight changes) with a sample image and it worked:

```
//open the image
I = rgb2gray(imread('img_0236.jpg'));

//extract the left stereo image
I1 = I(:,1:800);
//extract the right stereo image
I2 = I(:,801:1600);

points1 = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
[features1, valid_points1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);
[features2, valid_points2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1, features2);
matchedPoints1 = valid_points1(indexPairs(:, 1));    
matchedPoints2 = valid_points2(indexPairs(:, 2));
figure; showMatchedFeatures(I1, I2, matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2);
```

I downloaded the sample image from: http://www.stereomaker.net/java/spva/img_0236.jpg

Comment: Are the images you used (`kitchen.jpg` and `loops.jpg`) the same dimensions? You can check them with the function `size()`

Comment: The images were not of the same dimension. I resized the bigger image using the function imresize() and tried again. Unfortunately its the same error.

Comment: I used a sample stereo image from: http://www.stereomaker.net/java/spva/img_0236.jpg, and ran your code with some slight changes and it worked. Ill edit the answer to show you what I did. Could you try that and see if it works?

Comment: its still not working. I downloaded the image and ran the code. Same error. Same line. I am working on the 2015a version with all the required toolboxes. Am i missing some basic installation file?